# findByText for Kendo TreeView does not work when template is uded

Tags: javascript, kendo-ui, kendo-treeview

I have rendered the Kendo treeview using kendo template as follows:

```
 $("#TradingTreeView").kendoTreeView({
     loadOnDemand: false,
     template: kendo.template($("#TreeView-template").html())
 });
```

and the template is as follows:

```
<script id="TreeView-template" type="text/kendo-ui-template">
  <div class="section group">
        <div class="TradingSpaceText">
            #: item.text #
        </div>
  </div>
</script>
```

and when I use

```
var treeview = $("#TradingTreeView").data("kendoTreeView");
var TradingSummary= treeview.findByText("Trading Space Summary");
treeview.select(TradingSummary);
```

[image]
so in the above case I get "findByText" is not defined.
Please suggest the solution

Comment: Can you add the code where you define the variable `treeview`?

Comment: Added the 'treeview' variable

Comment: When I try it it works fine ([Dojo](http://dojo.telerik.com/OdUbu)). Can you modify it so you get the same error?

Comment: @Philipp my text is as above..refer Image showing textContent...

Comment: Can you modify the [Dojo](http://dojo.telerik.com/OdUbu) to get the behavior you are describing?